# How do I fix this pip install issue?

Tags: pip

I am trying to do pip install the OpenAI library and I get this error. I tried Windows shell in Visual Studio Code and I have Visual Studio C++ installed.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Python three separate times. The Windows console output is below. I have made sure I installed Visual Studio C++. My old computer never did this, so I don't have any idea on how to fix this. I am using Python 3.12.

```
cd C:\Users\yeet
pip install openai
```

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting openai
  Using cached openai-0.28.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.20 (from openai)
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting tqdm (from openai)
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Collecting aiohttp (from openai)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.6.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Using cached urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting colorama (from tqdm->openai)
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Using cached openai-0.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Using cached async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (98 kB)
Using cached urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\base_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_proto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_reqrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\connector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\cookiejar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\formdata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\hdrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_websocket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\locks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\multipart.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload_streamer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\pytest_plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\streams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tracing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\typedefs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_fileresponse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_middlewares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_request.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_response.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_routedef.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\worker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp\_cparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_headers.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_parser.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_websocket.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_cparser.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_find_header.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyi.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_websocket.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\hdrs.py.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcaiohttp/_websocket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp/_websocket.obj
      _websocket.c
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3097): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3238): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3293): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3744): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: See issue [#645](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/645#issuecomment-1757446970) on the openai issue tracker. You can use Python 3.11 or use OpenAI's latest beta of the openai package.

Comment: I will try that thank you!

Comment: It worked thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) or [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

That worked for me, because it's the beta that works with Python 3.12.